# Handling Multiple Errors from Server with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I make an API request, say using `fetch()` in my React front end to a 3rd party server, and there is an error, caught in a `catch{}` block in my React app, how do I know if there is one single error I can render to the dom for the user to react to, or if I need to loop though multiple errors in an array of errors and display those?

Is standard practice to check if the error value returned is an array with length > 1 and if so, map through those, else to render the single error to the screen? Clearly the code is different.

I have had issue with trying to render an object i.e. the array itself to the screen in the case it is an array of multiple errors. Just trying to understand best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can console.log the entire error object and decide what you want to do with it from there

```
catch (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
          },
        };
```

It depends entirely on the API function you’re calling and the React function that made the call.